# Stringifying large Array of JSON?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an array of about 200 complex Javascript objects. I am trying to stringify this data to use in an AJAX post request. On the serverside I am using ASP.NET MVC. How can I stringify this data to send it to the server? When I try to do JSON.Stringify the browser locks up.

In my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void SaveAs(SaveAsInputModel input)
```

Comment: 200 objects is not a lot. Are you sure it "locks up"? Maybe you are getting another error. The method name is `JSON.stringify` btw.

Comment: Each object has probably 20 properties, and one of those properties is also an array. I am using JSON.stringify, and if I wait long enough it eventually works. I am using Google Chrome as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use **XMLHttpRequest** It is a javascript object that allows to pass data between client and server. I have used it to pass entire XML object without trouble.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest

Hope it Helps you!

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that what was locking up my browser was not stringifying the array, but printing it to the console. The reason I was recieving a server error was because in my MVC project I inadvertantly had a limit on how many JSON objects could be deserialized by the server. The browser had no issue serializing the data.